# How do you type hint inner variable properly in overload

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

I have a overload function that mypy doesn't like because the return type hint conflicts with the inferred type.

```
Incompatible return value type (got "List[Tuple[Union[TestFunc, ScriptFunc], TestDocInfo]]", 
expected "Union[List[Tuple[TestFunc, TestDocInfo]], List[Tuple[ScriptFunc, TestDocInfo]]]")
```

I understand why the inferred type is different. I don't know what to do about it.

Is there some way to hint what `fn` when using an overload like this?

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import List, Type, Union, Tuple, overload
from types import ModuleType

def parse_test_doc_info(fn: Union[TestFunc, ScriptFunc]) -> TestDocInfo:
    ...

class TestDocInfo:
    ...

class TestFunc:
    ...

class ScriptFunc:
    ...

class TestPrefix:
    pat = "test_"

class ScriptPrefix:
    pat = "script_"

T_LT = List[Tuple[TestFunc, TestDocInfo]]
T_LS = List[Tuple[ScriptFunc, TestDocInfo]]

@overload
def foo(module: ModuleType, prefix: Type[TestPrefix] = ...) -> T_LT:
    ...

@overload
def foo(module: ModuleType, prefix: Type[ScriptPrefix]) -> T_LS:
    ...

def foo(module: ModuleType, 
        prefix: Union[Type[TestPrefix], Type[ScriptPrefix]] = TestPrefix
) -> Union[T_LT, T_LS]:
    test_or_script_functions = []
    for name, obj in module.__dict__.items():
        if name.startswith(prefix.pat):
            if callable(obj):
                fn: Union[TestFunc, ScriptFunc] = obj
                # ^ how do you type hint fn without conflicting with return type?
                info: TestDocInfo = parse_test_doc_info(fn)
                test_or_script_functions.append((fn, info))
    return test_or_script_functions  # <-- mypy errors on this
```

Comment: One side note: you don't annotate the undecorated implementation of `foo`; the whole point of `overload` is to provide multiple discrete sets of type hints rather than trying to provide one catch-all hint. `def foo(module, prefix): ...`

Comment: And without a more refined type for `module`, it doesn't make sense to hint `fn` at all, since there is no static information about what `module.__dict__.items()` might yield.

Comment: (This implies that you'll have to use something like `cast` to tell `mypy` that it's OK to accept whatever `fn` actually is as the argument to `parse_test_doc_info`, and that it will be your responsibility to ensure that `foo` is used with "compatible" modules.)

Comment: (There's really no need for the variable `fn` at all. It basically looks like you are trying to assert what type `obj` actually has.)

Comment: @chepner -- I annotate the undecorated so that pycharm can do it's magic with autocompletion in the primary function.

Comment: You  might want to use a generic: if `prefix` is `TestPrefix`, are you "guaranteeing" that`module` will produce `TestFunc` values? Something like `def foo(module: ModuleType[T], prefix: Type[T]) -> List[Tuple[T, TestDocInfo]]`.

Comment: (`ModuleType` itself is not generic, so you would define your own wrapper around it.)

Comment: @chepner -- good point about a module possibly not having either `TestFunc` or `ScriptFunc`.  Technically `foo` could return just `List`.

Comment: PyCharm doesn't know how to make use of the overload signatures for autocompletion? Seems like it would be trivial for it to infer `Union[A,B,C,...]` from the `A`, `B`, `C`, ... used in each overload.

Comment: I totally agree.  IIRC, there is a backlog ticket for that feature.

Comment: Son of a gun.. This satisfied mypy: `test_or_script_functions: List = []`

Comment: Another thought: `callable` does type narrowing, but it's much broader than the two type (`TestFunc` and `ScriptFunc`) that you care about. What if you replace that with `isinstance(obj, (TestFunc, ScriptFunc))`? (It think that does type narrowing as well.)

Comment: Huh. Out of curiosity, are you using 3.8 or earlier? Seems like a trivial thing to make a difference, but maybe it's the difference between `List` being generic and `list` not?

Comment: I left it out of the boiled down example, but `TestFunc` and `ScriptFunc` are actually `Protocol`s

Comment: This is 3.9.  I figure when you explicitly type hint `test_or_script_functions` it must be essentially telling mypy not to infer anything further.  In fact, using `test_or_script_functions: list = []` works too...  It kinda makes sense in hindsight, now that I think about it.

Comment: @chepner answering your question _'are you "guaranteeing"'_; yes.  modules only contain functions that start with `"test_"` or `"script_"` but not both.

Comment: Yeah. I'm not a big fan of unions in the first place, if only because I get them mixed up with sum types too often :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `foo` returning `Union[T_LT, T_LS]` you can make it return `List[Tuple[Union[TestFunc, ScriptFunc], TestDocInfo]]`:

```
T_LT = List[Tuple[TestFunc, TestDocInfo]]
T_LS = List[Tuple[ScriptFunc, TestDocInfo]]
T_LTS = List[Tuple[Union[TestFunc, ScriptFunc], TestDocInfo]]

@overload
def foo(module: ModuleType, prefix: Type[TestPrefix] = ...) -> T_LT:
    ...

@overload
def foo(module: ModuleType, prefix: Type[ScriptPrefix]) -> T_LS:
    ...

def foo(module: ModuleType, 
        prefix: Union[Type[TestPrefix], Type[ScriptPrefix]] = TestPrefix
) -> T_LTS:
    test_or_script_functions = []
    for name, obj in module.__dict__.items():
        if name.startswith(prefix.pat):
            if callable(obj):
                fn: Union[TestFunc, ScriptFunc] = obj
                info: TestDocInfo = parse_test_doc_info(fn)
                test_or_script_functions.append((fn, info))
    return test_or_script_functions
```

Or you could hint `test_or_script_functions` the same way you did the return:

```
test_or_script_functions: Union[T_LT, T_LS]
```

But a don't think there's a way to solve it by only changing `fn`'s hint

Comment: I had the same thought, unfortunately returning `List[Tuple[Union[TestFunc, ScriptFunc], TestDocInfo]]` results in mypy: `Overloaded function implementation cannot produce return type of signature 1` & `Overloaded function implementation cannot produce return type of signature 2`

Comment: And `test_or_script_functions: Union[T_LT, T_LS] = []` will cause mypy to complain: `Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "List[<nothing>]", variable has type "Union[List[Tuple[TestFunc, TestDocInfo]], List[Tuple[ScriptFunc, TestDocInfo]]]")`